# Marionette.CompositeView, how to pass parameters to Marionette.ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I would like to access the app.vent from Marionette.ItemView.

Maybe an option could be to pass a parameter (`app.vent`) to `Marionette.ItemView` from `Marionette.CompositeView`.

Here my code:

```
// view/compositeView.js
define([
    'marionette',
    'views/item'
], function (Marionette, itemView) {
    var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({ 
        itemView: itemView
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

P.S.:
I cannot access the app from itemView because there is a problem of circular dependency.

```
app -> view/compositeView -> view/itemView
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

v0.9 added an `itemOptions` attribute that can be used for this. It can either be an object literal or a function that returns an object literal.

```
Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: MyItemViewType,

  itemViewOptions: {
    some: "option",
    goes: "here"
  }

});
```

All of the `key: "value"` pairs that are returned by this attribute will be supplied to the itemview's options in teh initializer

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    options.some; //=> "option"
    options.goes; //=> "here"
  }
});
```

Additionally, if you need to run specific code for each itemView instance that is built, you can override the `buildItemView` method to provide custom creation of the item view for each object in the collection.

```
  buildItemView: function(item, ItemView){

    // do custom stuff here

    var view = new ItemView({
      model: item,
      // add your own options here

    });

    // more custom code working off the view instance

    return view;
  },
```

For more information, see:

- [the change log for v0.9](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/changelog.md#v090-view-commit-logs)
- [the CollectionView documentation for itemViewOptions](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemviewoptions) - note that CompositeView extends from CollectionView, so all CollectionView docs are valid for CompositeView as well
- [the buildItemView annotated source code](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-45)

Comment: _itemViewOptions_ is not used anymore, you have to use _childViewOptions_ now.

Answer (score 14):

Since Marionette v2.0.0, **childViewOptions** is used instead of **itemViewOptions** to pass parameters to the child view:

```
var MyCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  childView: MyChildView,
  childViewOptions: function(model, index) {
    return {
      vent: this.options.vent
    }
  }
});

var MyChildView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
      // var events = options.vent;
  }
});

new MyCompositeView({ vent: app.vent, collection: myCollection});
```

But to work with events, lets use [Marionette.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) instead of passing *app.vent* to the view.